# Electrostatic-Potential Difference

Tags: electrostatics, work, potential, potential-energy, voltage

Why we use work done in case of potential difference?

$$\Delta V= W/q$$

Comment: Please elaborate what exactly you want to know - currently I have no idea what you're trying to ask.

Answer (score 2):

Electrical potential is just a potential energy just like any other form of potential energy. If we move a charge $Q$ from some point $A$ to a different point $B$ then the difference in the potential energy $\Delta V$ is the amount of work $W_\text{ab}$ we have to put in to move the charge, or conversely the amount of work we can get out as the charge moves.

This work will depend on the size of the charge $Q$ so for convenience we define the electrical potential as the work per unit charge i.e. $W/Q$. So we end up with the definition of the potential difference between the points $A$ and $B$:

$$ \Delta V_\text{ab} = \frac{W_\text{ab}}{Q} $$